# Django : File object is not Json serializable

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to send back a file as a response to my post request but i get this error file object is not json serializable , so how do i send a file back as a response for my post request :

```js
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def Upload_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        queryset = Uploads.objects.all()
        uploads=queryset.filter(owner=request.user)
        serializer = UploadSerializer(uploads, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = UploadSerializer(data=request.data)
      
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save(owner=request.user)
            respFile=list(File.objects.filter(id=str(File.objects.latest('created_at'))))
            serializers=Fileserializers(respFile,read_only=True,many=True)
            return Response(serializers)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: You need to use a serializer to serialize the `File` object...

Comment: What if you use `return Response(serializers.data)`

Comment: i have  a custom serializer for the file object and i used that one

Answer (score 0):

You cannot attach a file in serializer for response. Instead you can do one of the following.

1. You can attach the file to the request 'Content-Disposition' header

   response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="file.extension"'
2. Send the link of the file in your key in serializer. Default behaviour of the serializer.

   {'file':'http://absolute_url_to_my_file'}

Comment: why not, it is working for me i m using the serializer to send files and post them

Comment: Not while posting the data, while returning the response with the file @Rihabsabri. If there are other ways as well if i am missing pls correct me.

Comment: while posting the data i  m using a serializer to verify if it's valid, and while returning the file object as a response i m using another serializer to transform it to native python datatype to be sent.